# Wind has a weird stop in smoke simulation

Tags: smoke-simulation

I created a smoke explode;  and added wind (30 lvl).

In frame 32 of the animation there is a weird stop, and smoke changes color. But only in frame 32. How can it be fixed?

https://youtu.be/3ZiuBbAhqQE

Blender version 3.0

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by changing the cache path; effectively deleting the cache.

Comment: Ah yes, unfortunately caches in blender have a problem of being rather sticky and not clearing with changes.  I sometimes find the cache folder and delete, or change some sim parameter that I know will reliably reset the cache.  Sigh.